# Best way of checking password against several number of requierements

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP and the challenge is the password entered by the User from the Login Page should be checked and this password has several requirements for it to be accepted by the logic I am trying to implement (for the login form). Considering that at least 2 complexity requirements must be met what could be the best way to achieve this in PHP (without any framework)
Requierements for check:
#1 Uppercase letters of European languages (A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
#2 Lowercase letters of European languages (a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)
#3 Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
#4 Non-alphanumeric characters (special characters): (~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/) Currency symbols such as the Euro or British Pound aren't counted as special characters for this policy setting.
Any Unicode character that's categorized as an alphabetic character but isn't uppercase or lowercase. This group includes Unicode characters from Asian languages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hmm...If I understand you...Try this:

```
        function checkPassword(string $password) {
$conditions = ["minimumChars" => 8,"specialChars" => 1, "upperCase" => 1];
$error = 0;
    if(strlen($password) < $conditions["minimumChars"]) {
        $error++;
    }
    if(preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $password) < $conditions["upperCase"] ) {
        $error++;
    }
    if(preg_match_all('/\X/u', $password) < $conditions["specialChars"]) {
        $error++;
    }

if ($error <= 1) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Passwords should not be restricted in such way. It is only going to make them weaker.

Comment: True. But its what op requested.

Comment: It's actually unclear what he requested.

Comment: Sorry for unclarity in the question I'm a beginner, there are four conditions: uppercase, lowercase, greater than 8 and special char and I am supposed to write the function checking the user-entered password, which should meet at least 2 out of 4 requirements. and thanks for the answers I already got the idea from it.